# How can I get an event to happen in a frame when pressing a button in another frame?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython. I have a main frame, you press a button and it takes you to another frame, where you read in some data. Then press a button. How can I transfer this data onto my other frame?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use PubSub. It makes communicating between classes a breeze! I wrote a tutorial on PubSub [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/).

You can also read about it at the following:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Controlling%20GUI%20with%20pubsub
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub

Basically you set up a listener in the first frame and then you publish the data from the second frame to the first and update appropriately.